# How to assign an HttpResponse response of custom array of objects returned from webapi to an object of same array type in typescript angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

I am using asp.net core with angular in VSCODE for the first time, working on a small project from video tutorial. Below is my component typescript file - **index-actors.component.ts**

```
    import { actorDTO } from './../actors.model';
import { ActorsService } from './../actors.service';
      import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

      @Component({
        selector: 'app-index-actors',
        templateUrl: './index-actors.component.html',
        styleUrls: ['./index-actors.component.css']
      })
      export class IndexActorsComponent implements OnInit {

        constructor(private actorService:ActorsService) { }
        actors!: actorDTO[];
        colunsToDisplay=['name','actions'];
        totalAmountOfRecords: string | null | undefined;
        currentPage=1;
        pageSize=5;
        ngOnInit(): void {
          this.actorService.get().subscribe((response:HttpResponse<actorDTO[]>)=>{
          this.actors=response.body;
          this.totalAmountOfRecords=response.headers.get("totalAmountOfRecords");
          });
        }

        delete(id:number){

        }

      }
```

I am getting an error at the line

> this.actors=response.body;

The error says

> Error: Type 'actorDTO[] | null' is not assignable to type 'actorDTO[]'.
> Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'actorDTO[]'.
> 21           this.actors=response.body;

I can't seem to figure out how to fix this issue. Why can a response body which has an array of actorDTO[] be assigned directly to actors which is itself an array of actorDTO?

**tsconfig.json**

```
    /* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

**actors.services.ts**

```
      import { observable, Observable } from 'rxjs';
  import { environment } from './../../environments/environment';
  import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
  import { actorCreationDTO, actorDTO } from './actors.model';
  import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
  import { formatDateFormData } from '../utilities/utils';

  @Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
  })
  export class ActorsService {

    constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
    private apiURL=environment.apiURL+"/actors";

    get(): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get<actorDTO[]>(this.apiURL, {observe:'response'});
    }
    create(actor: actorCreationDTO){
      const formData= this.buildFormData(actor);
      return this.http.post(this.apiURL,formData);
      }
    private buildFormData(actor:actorCreationDTO) : FormData{
      const formData=new FormData();
      formData.append('name',actor.name);
      if(actor.biography){
        formData.append('biography',actor.biography);
      }
      if(actor.dateOfBirth){
        formData.append('dateOfBirth',formatDateFormData(actor.dateOfBirth));
      }
      if(actor.picture){
        formData.append('picture',actor.picture);
      }
  return formData;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you please post your `tsconfig.json` file?

Comment: Strict typing is set in your tsconfig.  In your component if you put `actors!: actorDTO[] | null` the error should go away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your tsconfig strict typing is  set by default.  If you look at the Angular doc for `HttpResponse` the type of `body` is `T | null`.  So the response body could potentially be `actorDTO[] | null`.

Since strict typing is set, you need to account for the potential null case in the response body.

#### Option 1

Type your actors property to account for `null`.

```js
// IndexActorComponent
actors!: actorDTO[] | null;
```

#### Option 2

Use the `||` to assign an empty array if the response body is null.  With this use can keep you actors typed as `actors!: actorDTO[]`.

```
this.actors = response?.body || [];
```

- https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpResponse
- https://angular.io/guide/strict-mode
- https://indepth.dev/posts/1402/bulletproof-angular

Comment: I am new to typescipt as well. What is the usual standard value strict typing in a development environment? Should it be removed or set to false?

Comment: Since Angular 11 strict is enabled by default on all new projects.  Strict mode adds extra type safety features to your project.  It's a personal choice if you want to use it or not.  I believe it's recommend to keep enabled but is not mandatory.  Check my edit for links to a couple articles about strict mode.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing `strict: true` and please read more about it at https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig. This option `strict` that is set to `false` is forcing you to put `!` when declaring a property in a class and to be honest is sometimes annoying. :)

Also consider adding `strictNullCheks: false` to your `tsconfig.json`.

On more option that will maybe work is this `this.actors = response.body || [];`